# Align numpy slice for minimum distance between rows

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice, reshape

I have an array `a` with *r* rows of data and *c* columns:

```
a = np.array([
[1,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
[3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,6],
[0,4,2,1,2,3,4,5,1],
[1,2,3,3,5,1,2,3,4],
[1,1,1,2,2,4,5,1,2]
])
```

I'm interested in aligning a slice of `a` with shape (*r*, *s*) with *s* < *c* in such a way that the deviation between rows are minimized.

For example, if I choose *s* = 5:

[image]

would be the ideal solution.  Essentially, the starting index of each row is shifted in order to minimize the difference between rows.

My current approach has me iterating through each row (starting at 1), and comparing the distance with the row shifted one index to the left to the row before it, and also to the right.  If the distance is smaller than it would be without any shifting, I enter a while loop and continue shifting in a given direction until the distance stops decreasing.  When shifting exceeds the bounds of the array, I pad it with -1s.  It is slow, inefficient, and riddled with cases that make it impractical.

Is there a better/easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: _"My current approach has me..."_ Pls show that current approach. How do you define _"deviation between rows"_? Mean Squared difference? Root Mean Squared Diff? Sum of differences?

Comment: Why would your ideal solution not be `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3]` for all rows but the last which would be `[1, 1, 2, 2, 4]`? For that arrangement, the *total* distance over all pair-wise rows is 1, versus the total distance in your "ideal" solution which is 3.

Comment: @blorgon The shape would be (r, s).  s is smaller than c.  Here, c is 9, but s is only 5.  That is, I only want 5 consecutive elements from each row in a.  I'm looking for the starting indices that would make each row most alike.